# How can i integrate payfort payment gateway in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, payfort

I need to integrate **payfort** **payment** **gateways** to transfer money to other user account.

I found some links as 
[github documentation suggest](https://github.com/payfort/start-php)
but not getting exactly.

I have to do this in **codeigniter** **project**.
Pls suggest any solution...

Comment: I want apply PayFort payment gateway in my codeigniter project, please give any suggestion ? Thanks!

Comment: Hey guys! did you find an answer or a solution to this question?